# Java ClassCastException when casting a list back to its type

Tags: java, hibernate

```
List<Contact> contacts = dataManager().getContactsDao().getAll();
```

When I need to convert it to `ArrayList<Contact>`, instead of iterating the list and copy the items to the arraylist one by one, is there any other way to do it?

I have tried

```
ArrayList<Contact> contactarylist =
    (ArrayList<Contact>) dataManager().getContactsDao().getAll();
```

but it will result a `ClassCastException` because of the `List` to `ArrayList` is not allowed.

Thanks

Comment: What is the signature of `ContactsDAO.getAll()`?

Comment: And more importantly, show us the implementation of `ContactsDao.getAll`

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `List<>` interface not concrete class in your code.
The hibernate does not return ArrayList as its result set implementation.
But it returns a List. Same your code, all the variables should be defined as interfaces but they can initilized with the concrete class.

```
List<Contact> cs = new ArrayList<>();
...
cs = dataManager().getContactsDao().getAll();
```

And if you do need to have ArrayList use the constructor that takes collection

```
List<Contact> cs = new Arraylist<>(dataManager().getContactsDao().getAll());
```